# change permalink through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to change my permalink example www.testing.com/1234/"titlename" instead of www.testing.com/1234/, how to do i change it through .htaccess? Below are my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /clients/ohmynews/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?did=$1

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ listing.php?lid=$1

RewriteRule ^/?search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search.php?keys=$1

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://wipstage.com/clients/ohmynews/web/
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Remove code snippet tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this line into your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/?$  detail.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

As i do not know your actual running file path, so make sure you put your original running file path in my code.

Or let me know your file name with location, i will edit my answer.

Comment: my actual path is the detail.php, i will trying now

Comment: okay. Is detail.php is inside any subfolder? because changes need to be done accordingly.

Comment: it's correct if i change like this? 
RewriteRule ^/?article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?did=$1&title=$2

Comment: First thing in this is there syntax issue. You have to write like: RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?did=$1&title=$2 but make sure only id parameter will be defined through this. Title will be null.

Comment: its i need to add --> $request = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'); into detail.php?

Comment: Well, one easy way you can get these parameters is just do $_REQUEST['id'] or $_REQUEST['title'] in detail.php. You can also do print_r($_REQUEST) to see all parameters with their value.

Comment: sorry for late reply, i tried it also cant work, i below are my php part, its any error on it?

Comment: <?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
include_once 'includes/settings.php';
sec_session_start();
$result="";
if ( ( isset ($_GET['did']) && !empty($_GET['did']) ) ){
 $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles where art_id = ?");
 $stmt5->bind_param('s', $_GET['did']);
 $stmt5->execute();
 $stmt5->store_result();
 $resultrow5 = array();
 stmt_bind_assoc($stmt5, $resultrow5);
} while($stmt5->fetch()){
$request = trim($_REQUEST['id'], '/');
print_r ($_REQUEST['id']);
?>

Comment: sorry for i cant paste the whole code due to the word limitation

Comment: please upload a new question for this. so that it will get more idea about the issue.

Comment: One more thing, are you getting any results from print_r($_GET) in detail.php ?